# How to mock the StringBuilder class

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405250/how-to-unit-test-a-switch-statement-with-a-dependency-on-console), I would like to know how to mock a **StringBuilder** class. The way they are mocking the Console class is brilliant:

You need an interface defining your dependency:

```
public interface IConsoleService
{
    string ReadLine();
    void WriteLine(string message);
}
You create a default implementation for it:

public class ConsoleService : IConsoleService
{
    public string ReadLine()
    {
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

What would be the approach to mocking the **StringBuilder.Append** method?

So far what I have is this:

```
public interface IStringBuilderService
{
    string Append(string line);
    StringBuilder s
}

public class StringBuilderService : IStringBuilderService
{
    public string Append(string line)
    {
        return this.ToString() += line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why?  I don't understand what mocking buys you here.  It's a library class; doesn't cross boundaries.

Comment: @duffymo for practice

Comment: Bad practice does you little good.  It only makes bad habits.  First we make our habits; then our habits make us.  Save your energy and learn how to mock correctly.

Comment: @duffymo great, could you recommend a place to start?

Comment: Read the docs for the mock library you like to use.  I can tell you where NOT to look - don't mock StringBuilder.

Comment: I would add, don't expose StringBuilder as a parameter to a public interface, or pass it around.  I realize there could be situations where the public interface has internally "lazy" evaluation, and depending on some condition, the StringBuilder may or may not be reified as a string.  But, for that, just pass the darn StringBuilder in to your sut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though, there is rarely a need to mock `StringBuilder`, I'll assume you need it for trial purpose.. so here is one possible way to mock it.

Your default implementation class needs to wrap an instance of `StringBuilder`.

```
public interface IStringBuilderService
{
  IStringBuilderService Append(string line); // mimic the StringBuilder Append signature
  StringBuilder S { get; }
 }

public class StringBuilderService : IStringBuilderService
{
    private StringBuilder _actualStringBuilder;

    public StringBuilder S
    {
     get { return _actualStringBuilder; }
    }  

    public StringBuilderService() // you could also take in a parameter if you wish to initialize the variable
    {
     _actualStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    } 

    public IStringBuilderService Append(string line)
    {
        _actualStringBuilder.Append(line);
        return this; 
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
     return _actualStringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

The reason we need an instance of `StringBuilder` wrapped up in the concrete class is because `Console` is a static resource, and hence accessed without an instance variable requirement. `StringBuilder` will be per instance, and hence we need a variable encapsulating that.

Once you have this interface, you can use this interface wherever `StringBuilder` manipulation is required.

And for your tests, you could use a mock of this interface.

Comment: this looks kick-ass, yaar

Comment: what would IStringBuilderService look like? same as mine?

Comment: added the definition of the interface.. the append method of the interface needs to mimic the StringBuilder definition for consistency's sake (no hard rule)  except instead of StringBuilder, the IStringBuilderService is our abstraction, so we'll return that.

Comment: @PleaseStopUpvotingMe fixed the return type typo of ToString()

Comment: thank you. when you say "Your default implementation class needs to wrap an instance of StringBuilder." ---- does this mean that i need to use the stringbuilderservice class instead of stringbuilder?

Comment: nope. i mean StringBuilder. basically the reason we write a wrapper interface/default implementation is to hide/abstract an actual resource (StringBuilder in this case) so that it's operations can be mocked. The Console example doesn't need a wrapped instance since, Console is a single Static class. (System.Console) But for our case, StringBuilder is per use of StringBuilderService and hence we need a per instance wrapper

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103504/discussion-between-pleasestopupvotingme-and-raja-nadar).